# JButton with background image and backlighting

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, imageicon

I'm writing checkers. So, every cell is JButton, it has image (`ImageIcon`).

I want **JButton** that has background image and backlighting (for example, blue of red), because I want to show user available turns. Is it possible?

Now if I create new `JButton(Icon icon)` and then `setBackground(Color.BLUE);`
background is ignored.

Comment: I'd use a compound solution.  The actual cell would start out as a `JPanel`.  This is what I would use to render the image and highlighting to.  On top of this I would add the button (making sure it's transparent)

Comment: *"I want to show user available turns"*  This seems part of the logic inherent to the model.  We would then look to ways to render that model appropriate for each cell.

Comment: Calling `setContentAreaFilled(true)` on your JButton may help.

Comment: @VGR, it's the easiest way! thank you!
But how I can change the color of this border?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set its border color to BLUE or RED (I believe this is what you are looking for as an answer)

Try this statement:

```
chessButton.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.GREEN));
```

Painting JButton's border is not effected by image icon, therefore if you want to create a highlight effect and set border's color you should use BorderFactory. You can also have various effects for the border through [BorderFactory](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/border.html)

If you want complete background highlighted or some special effect then have two separate image of each cell i.e. one normal image and one highlighted image. When you want to show user its available turns, simply update the respective cells with their corresponding highlighted image